# What is killing my cypress trees?

Tags: urban-gardening

We planted a new row of cypress trees, approx a month ago. They are about 1.5 m tall and stand in direct sunlight for most of the day. We water them regularly with DIY.
At first they were doing well, but then yellow spots appeared which quickly turned brown.
As of now, many of them now look completely yellow-brown and even those which remained green have yellow spots inside.

I don't see any sign of canker, the bark seems completely healthy.

What should i do to save the remaining green cyprus trees?
Is there anything to do for the yellow ones?

climate: mediterraenan (tel aviv)

[photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NjQU0.jpg)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exact same thing happened to me.  Everyone on here will tell you a million different things including what you shouldn’t do.  They told me not to touch the root ball.  But as my trees were dying anyways, I dug them up and and it was clear that the clay they came in was harder than cement and not allowing the roots to grow or breathe.  I broke up the cement root ball as much as possible and replanted the trees and they instantly improved.

Comment: cool thanks, I'll check the roots